# How do I read .bin file in Python? And why do I get weird looking outputs?

Tags: python

Here I'm trying to read a .bin file in PyCharm, I made a for in loop with range to make the reading limited because the file is so big (around 8GB)

```
read = open("D:\Office\Hadith Library\data\shamela.bin", 'rb')

for i in range(0,10):
  p = read.read(8)
  print(p , "\n")
```

The outcome I get from the print statement is:

```
b'PK\x03\x04\n\x00\x00\x00' 

b'\x00\x00\x9bt\x8bQ\x00\x00' 

b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' 

b'\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x0014' 

b'42.041/P' 

b'K\x03\x04\n\x00\t\x00\x00' 

b'\x00\xa4l\x8bQ\x00\x00\x00' 

b'\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' 

b'\x00\x1a\x00\x00\x00144' 

b'2.041/14'
```

Why's that? What's going on? appreciate the help!

Comment: Per e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals `\xhh` is a character with hex value `hh`. The `b` prefix indicates [_bytes_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), which is what you should expect from reading a file opened in binary mode.

Comment: That's a binary file, it stores bytes (well, I suppose all computer files do, but text files have a very standard encoding to go from those bytes to text we can read). Appropriately, you're using `rb` mode to read bytes of the binary file, 8 at a time. The `b'\x00'...` are Python's way of representing some bytes in hexadecimal; ASCII bytes are represented by a single character instead. It's your job to figure out how those bytes represent data and convert the `bytes` objects `b'...'` to that data in Python to do work.

Answer (score 0):

`.bin` files are usually "binary" files as suggested in its name, and this behaviour is expected - it's printing out binary.

If you know the format of the .bin file, you can try and decode it with `struct` - check the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). If you don't - then you typically won't be able to retrieve useful information from it.